# A question about Residence permit in China here (X1 Visa)

Tags: china

As the title says I entered China with a X1 visa intending to stay for some years attending a Master course.

After some days I went and registered to get my Residence card. All good and well but some days after I began having problems related with chronic fatigue and I am unable to go to class. The teacher texts me everyday telling me that I will be deported if I do not go to class and refuses to listen to me. I asked the university if I would get denied the Residence permit and they did not tell me that they would (neither they did tell me they would not, vague answers) but told me that I would need to leave the dormitory at the end of the semester if my attendance rate was not over 70% for this semester (it is like 20% right now so that is impossible) and I complied saying that I would have to go back to my country anyways for the abovementioned issues.

I am due to go collect my Residence permit in some weeks but my question is if it will be denegated or if simply I will not be granted another student visa in the future?

Thank you in advance for your answers. I have searched everywhere but I have not found a single answer to my question.

Comment: I saw that question but did not answer one or two of my points. For example my Visa is X1, not X2, and I actually attended some classes before having this problem so I would like to know what would happen in this case. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: I agree it's not a duplicate, in part because the potential duplicate has confusion in the question and so has multiple answers.  It's a bit late for the OP, but for the question I would say you must simply follow the visa process as long as you're there.  If you entered on the long-term visa that requires a Residence Permit in 30 days, you absolutely need to get the Residence Permit unless you leave before 30 days.  I don't know if quitting school has anything to do with a future visa, but over-staying a visa absolutely does.